# DNS configure issue with cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, vpn, cloudflare

Environment:
1.VPN Server: Amazon EC2 Ubuntu
2.DNS: cloudflare

---

I've setup a VPN Server on EC2 Ubuntu(Apache2.4 installed on the same machince),

dns setting in /etc/ppp/pptpd-options as following:

```
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

At this point,I'm able to connect the vpn by elastic IP or public-DNS given by aws.

However, I want to connect by my domain name(host name as: vpn.mydomain.org).I'm using cloudflare as my dns server.
The followings are what i did.
Cloudflare dns setting:

```
Type Name value 
A    vpn  54.x.x.x
A    www  54.x.x.x
```

After configuring like this, I can't connect vpn.mydomain.org as a vpn.
When I put vpn.mydomain.org in the browser, it shows my website.
I guest it's port miss configured. What should I do to make it right?

ps. For my security group rule, port 1723 is opened.

Comment: 54.x.x.x is the same for "www" and "vpn?"  Is 54.x.x.x your elastic IP?  `dig vpn.mydomain.org` and verify that it returns the elastic IP of thr instance as an A record.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to config 54.x.x.x for both www and vpn. 54.x.x.x is my elastic IP.

Comment: After dig vpn.mytdomain.org, I don't see any text include any IP address except 192.168.1.1(both www and vpn)

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work at CloudFlare.

"ps. For my security group rule, port 1723 is opened."

That port can't pass through CloudFLare's network. As in, with CloudFlare enabled you won't be able to access that port.

Please see: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-

So you'd need to leave CloudFlare disabled on vpn.mytdomain.org   or  change the port you're trying to access to something that is allowed through our network (one of the ports indicated in the link I included).  There isn't any way around this unfortunately. We don't open arbitrary ports at any plan level.